# Change the Forecolor of the ListBoxItem through DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

i'm facing a kindof stupid problem: i'm not able to change the Foreground color of a ListBoxItem with a DataTemplate. I'm sure theres a really simple solution for this but i just don't see it!

Here is my code:

```xml
    <ListBox Height="181" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,53,0,0" 
             Name="lstKeys" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="491">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="3">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image Width="32" Height="32" Stretch="Fill" Margin="3"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="image3" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                        <DockPanel Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product}" Foreground="Green"
                                       DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black"
                                       FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

At runtime the color ist the default System Color. Setting the Foreground Color directly by ListBox-Attribute doesn't work, i hope somebody can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I slightly modified the DataTemplate you're using (by setting Text={Binding}) and it works ok for me. Could you post some more code? For example, how are you setting the ItemsSource of the ListBox? Also, does the second textblock render in Bold font?

Comment: your Foreground=green does not work? or it just not work if you select an item in your listbox?

Comment: I'm doing nothing special, setting the  the itemsource by Code: 
List<ListEntry> lst = new List<ListEntry>(); lstKeys.ItemsSource = lst;
@blindmeis no it doesnt work at all, no matter what i click on or what i select

Comment: And ListEntry is a basic class? Does the bold font appear?

Comment: ListEntry is a simple POCO Class, and yes the bold Font appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi if i use your listbox its work like you want :) To know that the forecolor is working i changed the datatemplate to a fixed string in the textblock.

does your "green" Textblock show any text?

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="3">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image Width="32" Height="32" Stretch="Fill" Margin="3"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="image3" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                    <DockPanel Margin="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="the binding seems to be wrong" Foreground="Green"
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

EDIT: i know that problem :)

i override the SystemColors to get what i want.

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
  </ListBox.Resources>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Hi again, i think i expressed my self wrong :( ofcourse is 'Foreground="Green"' workling, what i need to change is, the Color that the selected Items at runtime has. The default System Color is here some kind of blue, thats is what i need to change, the Backgroundcolor of the selected Item. Have a look at this picture: http://goo.gl/kEgzi